# Unable to read the data more than 4096 (1 cluster size)

Tags: freertos

I am trying to write to an OSPI Flash drive MX25LM51245GM with the FreeRTOS+FAT.

The write to the SPI flash is successful for data size of >4096

But the read always returns 0 no matter what the size is

```
size_return = ff_fwrite (g_file_data, dat_len, 1, pxSourceFile);
size_return=ff_fread(g_read_buffer, dat_len, 1, pxSourceFile );
```

`g_read_buffer` always contains 0 for size >4096

---

After further invstigation I found that FF_ReadClusters is unable to read the required data

```
static FF_Error_t FF_ReadClusters( FF_FILE *pxFile, uint32_t ulCount, uint8_t *buffer )
{
uint32_t ulSectors;
uint32_t ulSequentialClusters = 0;
uint32_t ulItemLBA;
FF_Error_t xError = FF_ERR_NONE;

    while( ulCount != 0 )
    {
        if( ( ulCount - 1 ) > 0 )
        {
            ulSequentialClusters =
                FF_GetSequentialClusters( pxFile->pxIOManager, pxFile->ulAddrCurrentCluster, ulCount - 1, &xError );
            if( FF_isERR( xError ) )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

`ulSequentialClusters` is always 0

`ff_fread` >> `FF_Read` >> `FF_ReadClusters` >> `FF_GetSequentialClusters`

Any insights?